# java.rmi.UnmarshalException: unrecognized method hash: method not supported by remote object

Tags: java, rmi

I have two web application, the first one RMIServer contains the following

```
public interface EasyPDFGeneratorRemoteInterface extends Remote {

public File generatePDFAmin(File sourceFile) throws RemoteException ;
}

public class EasyPDFGenerator extends UnicastRemoteObject 
    implements EasyPDFGeneratorRemoteInterface {


    public File generatePDFAmin(File sourceFile)  {
//implementation details....
}
```

then an object of type EasyPDFGenerator is registered in the registry.

And the Second contains

```
public interface EasyPDFGeneratorRemoteInterface extends Remote {

public File generatePDFAmin(File sourceFile) throws RemoteException ;
}

class test {

private File generatePDF(File file) {

    File pdfFile = null;
    try {

        EasyPDFGeneratorRemoteInterface easyPDFGenerator = getRemoteEasyPDFGenerator();// get the remote object.
        easyPDFGenerator.getClass.getMethods();// the array contains the method generatePDFAmin.
        pdfFile = easyPDFGenerator.generatePDFAmin(file);// throws the exception.

    } catch (RemoteException ex) {

    }

}
}
```

I am not sure what could be causing the problem since am getting the remote object ,and it does contain the method that the UnmarshalException is thrown when it gets invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changed your remote interface definition without reploying all the .class files affected. If you're using a generated stub, you didn't regenerate that either.

Comment: do you think that exporting the remote interface as a jar  and using it in the second project is a good idea, or would your recommend another way ?

Comment: Yes, or else have a common project containing the remote interface and anything it depends on. What you mustn't do is physically copy the source to two projects. That way, they *will* diverge, sooner or later.